# ReactJS checkbox remain true even when unchecked

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am struggling to populate my state with some input fields data.
these are my fields:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="title"></input>
<input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} name="amount"></input>
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} name="is_published"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="isflat"></input>
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} name="isdhaka"></input>
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} name="isrent"></input>
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="name"></input>
```

and this my handle change method

```
handleChange = event => {
    const { purchase } = this.state;
    purchase[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ purchase });
    updateValidators(event.target.name, event.target.value);
  };
```

My problems, when I click on the checkbox, it becomes true as a value but when I unchecked again the checkbox, it remains true again as value.

I am not getting why it's occureing. If dont click on any checkbox, it returns false as value and when i click, it retrun true as value but problem is, when i uncheck the checkbox, it remains true yet

Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your `input` elements aren't responding to the `onChange` event, and subsequently, the changes in `state`, is because they aren't binded to the component's `state`.

I would recommend you to bind `text`/`number` input elements to the `value` props, and `checkbox` input elements to the `checked` props. As such, we can have different methods to handle the `onChange` event (`handleChange` and `handleCheckboxChange`)

For instance, this is how you can bind the input with `state`, by binding them to `value` and `checked` respectively.

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="title" value={this.state.purchase.title} />
<input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} name="amount" value={this.state.purchase.amount} />
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} name="is_published" checked={this.state.purchase.is_published} />
<input type="checkbox" name="isflat" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} checked={this.state.purchase.isflat} />
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} name="isdhaka" checked={this.state.purchase.isdhaka} />
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} name="isrent" checked={this.state.purchase.isdhaka} />
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="name" value={this.state.purchase.name} />
```

In addition, you should be using `setState`  to update your component's `state`:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    purchase: {
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }
  });
  // do the rest
}


handleCheckboxChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
  });
 // do the rest 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're are missing the value attribute on all of your elements.

Your code should be something like

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="title" value={this.state.purchase.title} />
<input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} name="amount" value={this.state.purchase.amount} />
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} name="is_published" value={this.state.purchase.is_published} />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox inputs, `input.target.value` does not indicate whether the checkbok is checked or not. The value of a checkbox won't change when you click on it, that's why you are only receiving `on` which is the default value. You need to use `event.target.checked` instead:

```
this.setState({
  purchase: {
    [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
handleChange = event => {
  const { purchase } = this.state;
  this.setState({ purchase:  {
    ...purchase,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  });
  updateValidators(event.target.name, event.target.value);
};
```

and in your checkboxes set values

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.purchase.is_published} onChange={this.handleChange} name="is_published" />
```

you mutate state in this line

```
purchase[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
```

this is a bad way